# How to use vector of vector for reading a graph?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, graph-algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
void addEdge( vector<vector<int> > adj, int, int);
void print_graph(vector<vector<int> > adj);


int main()
{

    vector<vector<int> > adj(4);
    addEdge(adj,1,2);     // edge from node 1 to node 2
    addEdge(adj,1,3);
    addEdge(adj,1,4);
    addEdge(adj,2,3);
    addEdge(adj,3,4);
    print_graph(adj);
    return 0;
}

void addEdge(vector<vector<int> > adj, int u , int v)
{
    adj[u].push_back(v);

}

void print_graph( vector<vector<int> > adj)
{
    for( int i = 0; i < adj.size() ; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0 ; j < adj[i].size(); j++ )
        {
            cout<< i+1 << " , " << cout<< adj[i][j]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I have written the code for reading the graph and printing it.
Prior to this for reading graph I used to use

```
vector<int>adj[5];
```

But I have been told that , use

```
`vector<vector<int> > adj`  or `list<list<int> > adj`
```

I tried but now I am getting **No output**.    ***( update)***

Can anyone help me in using **vector of vector** ?? Please help for **list of list** also.

Answer (score 3):

To use a `vector` of `vector`s you could write

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> adj(5); // Note: round parentheses
```

This works because standard vectors have a constructor that accepts the requested size as parameter and default-initializes all elements.

Being `adj` a vector of vectors the elements of `adj` will be initialized as empty vectors, that you can later fill with `push_back`.

Comment: Thank you for reply.   I have done changes the way you said but I am not getting output. Output screen is blank.

Comment: I have checked , in print_graph() , innermost for loop is not working. Control is not entering in innermost for loop ( and that's why nothing is printing on screen )  Why ??

Answer (score 2):

Your version of `addEdge` takes `adj` as a copy. You manipulate that copy which is then destroyed when the function returns. You need to use reference to access the outer adj:

```
void addEdge(vector<vector<int> >& adj, int u , int v)
{
    adj[u].push_back(v);

}
```

and use:

```
void print_graph(const vector<vector<int> >& adj)
```

to avoid another copy

Answer (score 0):

Vectors use zero-based indexing. `adj[0]` is the first element in the vector.

Also vectors start with no size. There will be no `adj[0]` element until you add one.

You may want to `adj.resize(4)` before you try and call `adj[u].push_back(v)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the vector adj, you have an empty vector. In your function addEdge, you access the entry at index u in adj. But remember, that is an empty vector. This is where your crash comes from.

I assume your function addEdge is supposed to add an entry to this adjacency matrix you are creating. Before that, you need to create space for that matrix. Meaning, you need to make space in your adj vector for the vectors it will contain, and you also need to make space in those vectors where you can put the edge information.

Once you have your vectors set up though, your print function will still print all 0's because your function addEdge makes a copy of the vector you are passing, then writes to that copy. The original adj vector will be unchanged. Be sure to pass the vector by pointer if you want to modify the original.